# Using python to interface with online forms and interface with javascript associated with "type=button" inputs

Tags: python, mechanize, spidermonkey

I need to fill an online form which has button running java-script in the background, I have successfully filled data in all the available fields using python mechanize module.

I have read that I can use spidermonkey to get such a task done. On clicking on the button named "browse", a window pop's up and a file that is stored on the server is selected and the Id of the file is returned to the original web-page.Th following are the HTML and javascript for the page:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5veiNJUXUAWWXdvRVY2cWcxbWc/edit?usp=sharing

Can you please suggest me a way to perform this ask as I am not acquainted with web-scraping and have no idea of which module to use to emulate the things the javascript is doing in python.

Answer (score 2):

According to mechanize's docs, it does not interact or deal with JavaScript in any way. I learned this the hard way, and I ended up using headless Selenium, which is effectively browser automation without any visual component.

Comment: I have also resorted to use Selenium but I feel its not an elegant solution as it makes the code less flexible. Is there any other module to take care of such cases?

I have also tried to emulate the process that java script is doing in python but the fields that the java script updates come up are read only variables(fields are- gtrnFileId, gtrnFieldId_UID and similarly for trp).